# How to set Flash Messages in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to figure out how to make flash messages in Aurelia.  I've created a custom element `flash-message` and required it in `app.html` but the message doesn't update.  It does display correctly if I set it to a default value.

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./resources/elements/flash-message"></require>
  <flash-message></flash-message>
</template>
```

**flash-message.html**

```
<template>
  <div class="alert alert-success">${message}</div>
</template>
```

**flash-message.js**

```
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class FlashMessage {
  @bindable({defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay}) message = 'Default';

  setMessage(newValue) {
    this.message = newValue;
  }
}
```

**object-detail.js**

```
import {FlashMessage} from './resources/elements/flash-message';

export class ObjectDetail {
  static inject() {return [FlashMessage]};

  constructor(flash) {
    this.flash = flash;
  }

  activate(params, routeConfig) {
    this.flash.setMessage('Activate');
  }
}
```

The `activate()` code is being called as well as the `setMessage()` method but the displayed messaged doesn't updated.  What am I missing?

Comment: Since custom elements are instantiated with multiple instances, you are working with two different instances of `FlashMessage`, and therefore the properties of one is not reflected in the other.

Answer (score 5):

Since you initially only require the template in `app.html` without instantiating the class in `app.js`, Aurelia treats it as a custom element, which means it has its own instance (not a singleton).  You are basically working with two different instances of `FlashMessage`, and therefore the properties of one is not reflected in the other.

If you want it to be instantiated as a singleton class, you'll also need to import the component in `app.js` and inject it in the constructor so that it is treated like a component rather than a custom element.

**app.js**

```
import {FlashMessage} from './resources/elements/flash-message';

@inject(FlashMessage)
export class App {
  constructor(flashMessage) {
    this.flashMessage = flashMessage;
  }
  // ...
}
```

**Confusion between Custom Element and Class/ViewModel**

Since all class properties are considered public, you don't even need the `setMessage(newValue)` method.  You can update the message property from `object-detail.js` like this:

```
this.flash.message = 'Activate';
```

Also, the `@bindable` line is intended to be used so that you can instantiate it with the variable value in the HTML code, like this:

```
<flash-message message="Show this message"></flash-message>
```

If you don't plan to use it like this, I would skip the whole `@bindable` line.  Your `flash-message.js` could be simplified to just this:

```
export class FlashMessage {
  constructor() {
    this.message = 'Default';
  }
}
```

**Use of Event Aggregator for Flash Messages**

I implemented a Flash Message class with similar goals, using the Toastr 3rd party library (just because I liked the UI).  But it's not hard to set it up any way you want.  The best approach, I believe, to allowing any part of your app to set a flash message is to use Aurelia's Event Aggregator.  The following code snippet might help you get it set up.

**flash-message.js**

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework'
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@inject(EventAggregator)
export class FlashMessage {

  constructor(eventAggregator) {
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    this.eventAggregator.subscribe('ShowFlashMessage', this.showMessage);
  }

  showMessage(message) {
    this.message = message;
    // hide after 10 seconds
    window.setTimeout(hideMessage, 10000);
  }

  hideMessage() {
    this.message = "";
  }
}
```

This is obviously simplified and doesn't handle multiple messages, or renewing the timer when a second message is posted, but it should be enough to get you started.

To set a message from another part of your app, you can simply first inject the eventAggregator and save in your constructor, and then publish a message like this:

```
this.eventAggregator.publish('ShowFlashMessage', "Record saved");
```

**My Toastr Implementation in Aurelia:**

Similar to what you did, I created a common class called `FlashMessage` in a subfolder called `common` in my `src` folder.

```
//src/common/flash-message.js
import * as toastr from 'toastr';
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework'
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@inject(EventAggregator)
export class FlashMessage {

    constructor(eventAggregator) {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.eventAggregator.subscribe('ewFlashSuccess', this.showSuccess);
        this.eventAggregator.subscribe('ewFlashInfo', this.showInfo);
        this.eventAggregator.subscribe('ewFlashWarning', this.showWarning);
        this.eventAggregator.subscribe('ewFlashError', this.showError);

        // Not sure why this is not working... if you figure it out, let me know.
        toastr.options = {
            positionClass: "toast-top-left",
            showEasing: "swing",
            hideEasing: "linear",
            showMethod: "fadeIn",
            hideMethod: "fadeOut",
            preventDuplicates: true,
            closeButton: true
        }
    }

    showSuccess(message) {
        toastr.success(message, null, {preventDuplicates: true, closeButton: true});
    }

    showInfo(message) {
        toastr.info(message, null, {preventDuplicates: true, closeButton: true});
    }

    showWarning(message) {
        toastr.warning(message, null, {preventDuplicates: true, closeButton: true});
    }

    showError(message) {
        toastr.error(message, null, {preventDuplicates: true, closeButton: true});
    }

}
```

Then, I injected and instantiated it in `app.js` like this:

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { FlashMessage } from './common/flash-message';
@inject(Core, FlashMessage)
export class App {
  constructor(core, flashMessage) {
    this.flashMessage = flashMessage;
  }
  // ...
}
```

I also had to require the CSS in `app.html` like this:

```
<require from="toastr/build/toastr.min.css"></require>
```

All of this depends on having `Toastr` properly installed (I installed it with `npm install toastr --save`) and correctly required as a dependency in `aurelia.json` (I'm using the CLI).

```
                {
                    "name": "toastr",
                    "path": "../node_modules/toastr",
                    "main": "toastr",
                    "resources": [
                        "build/toastr.min.css"
                    ]
                },
```

**Final thoughts**

Please also see Ashley Grant's response for a better explanation of getting a handle on your ViewModel as well as a working GistRun to fix your immediate issues.  Ashley is much more experienced than I am with Aurelia so if parts of my solution don't work, his most likely will!  :-)

Comment: If you want to take the answer I posted and add it to your's feel free.

Comment: Thanks, you're too kind!  I appreciate you leaving some space for the "little guys" like me to learn and grow!  If you see anything in my fully edited response that is incorrect or misleading, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend getting a reference to the ViewModel of the custom element using `view-model.ref="flash"`. Note that you won't be able to use this from the `activate` callback though as no binding will have occurred at that point in the page lifecycle. I'm using the `attached` callback in my example below.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=76ef47a5327a34560737f4ade1038305**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./flash-message"></require>
  <flash-message view-model.ref="flash"></flash-message>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  attached(params, routeConfig) {
    this.flash.setMessage('Activate');
  }
}
```

**flash-message.html**

```html
<template>
  <div class="alert alert-success">${message}</div>
</template>
```

**flash-message.js**

```js
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class FlashMessage {
  @bindable({defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay}) message = 'Default';

  setMessage(newValue) {
    this.message = newValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From LStarky's message, I discovered toastr which I wasn't aware of before so I ended up just using that library instead.

`npm install toastr --save`

**aurelia.json** (Under bundle -> dependencies)

```
{
  "name": "toastr",
  "path": "../node_modules/toastr",
  "main": "toastr",
  "resources": [
    "build/toastr.min.css"
  ]
}
```

**app.html**

```
<require from="toastr/build/toastr.min.css"></require>
```

**view-model.js**

```
import toastr from 'toastr';

action() {
  toastr.success('Toastr visible!');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I would have recommended, honestly :-) Cheers!

Comment: Glad you found a solution!